# jQuery: force specific button click when Enter key is pressed

Tags: jquery, click, keypress, keycode

I have a textbox where user can enter a category, and when they press enter I want to use jQuery to click a specific button in the form, but so far this isn't working, and I can't see any syntax errors that might be causing a problem.. It's posting back to the form, but with a different (default) button, not the one in the jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#newcategory').keypress(function(e) {
        var KEYCODE_ENTER = 13;
        if (e.keyCode == KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('input#addnewcategory').click();
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:
Taking out the setTimeout fixed the issue, although I'm not sure why. In other areas of my application I need it otherwise it won't force the button click.

```
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('input#newcategory').keypress(function(e) {
                var KEYCODE_ENTER = 13;
                if (e.keyCode == KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    $('input#addnewcategory').click();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Does the `if (e.keyCode == KEYCODE_ENTER) {}` part run? Or does the issue lie with `$('input#addnewcategory').click();` Also, why is the setTimeOut needed?

Comment: (e.keyCode == KEYCODE_ENTER) {} works when an alert() is added. The timeout is because I've had problems forcing a button click without it; taking it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: What's in your `$('input#addnewcategory')` click event handler?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working code

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#addnewcategory").click();
    }
});
```

You could also change your code to put the keypress button event to the document instead of input#newcategory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#newcategory').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $('input#addnewcategory').trigger("click");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#newcategory').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('input#addnewcategory').click();
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default action when pressing the enter key inside a text input is to submit the form that input belongs to. So before processing the key press event, you need to call

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Otherwise the form will be submitted before your handler can execute.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#newcategory').keyup(function(e) {
        var KEYCODE_ENTER = 13;
        if (e.keyCode == KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('input#addnewcategory').click();
            });
        }
    });
});

$('input#addnewcategory').click(function () {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your call to `setTimeout` is missing a *delay*:</strike>
Apparently this is not required. [Some sources](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) say it's required, [other say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) it's not. By my testing it was not required (Chrome) but it defaults to `0`, so I'd still advice to be explicit.

```
setTimeout(function(){}, milliseconds)
```

**Regarding triggering events:**
Invoking a `click` usually has to come from a *trusted event*. I usually describe these as "user driven events" or "events that requires user interaction" (but that's simplifying it). All browsers are probably not smart enough to recognize that an anonymous function inside a `setTimeout` is triggered from a trusted event, like `keypress`.

> In Firefox, an event is trusted if it is invoked by the user and not trusted if it is invoked by script. In Internet Explorer, all events are trusted except that are created with the createEvent method.

More about [Trusted events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120614/#trusted-events).